# best approach for tracking daily calculated numbers (analytics)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, analytics

.Using Mongoid (mongodb), RoR, Delayed_job, and clockwork, im able to calculate transaction amounts and store them nightly.

But my question is, what storage options do I have for approaches to retain daily, monthly, yearly totals of these numbers?

i.e. would this approach be appropriate for the storage?
mongodb collection

```
AccountAnalytics{
  "account_id":{XXXXXXXXXXX},
  "period":"month",
  "date_start": "2013/01/01",
  "date_end": "2013/01/31",
  "value": 3125.84
},
  "account_id":{XXXXXXXXXXX},
  "period":"day",
  "date_start": "2013/01/02",
  "date_end": "2013/01/02",
  "value": 200.13
}
```

Then I could filter/search based on 'period' and dates to put into graphs.  My worry is that this will produce too much data to be efficient.

Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: You worry that daily aggregates will produce too much data? Aren't you worrying about raw data entries?

Comment: yes. 377(365+12) per account isnt that much, but with a few hundred accounts I would think that it becomes sluggish.

Comment: I think you need to measure things and then act. Not follow what some guys on the internet might say.

Comment: isnt StackOverflow designed and used to share knowledge and caveats?  Im just asking for thoughts on data structure

Comment: What I meant to say: that structure should work. As to "I would think it'll become sluggish" - there's not much to say, since it's completely unfounded.